# both of them worked what is the difference between list and tuple here

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am confused the output is the same and I know that lists are mutable and tuple immutable what is the difference here

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
axes = plt.plot(x,y)
```

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,4])
axes = plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Lists and tuples can be interchanged in a lot of cases. They support the same read operations.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between tuples and lists are irrelevant here. `figsize` just needs to be an ordered pair of numbers. Internally, it's probably doing something like

```
width = figsize[0]
height = figsize[1]
```

and this indexing will work the same with both types.

They'll usually be interchangeable for anything that just needs to read an ordered sequence, since you can index and iterate over tuples and lists the same way. The differences only matter if the contents need to be updated, since tuples are immutable.

Comment: Thank you it was helpful